# Post-Build should ignore Exit-Code of Sub-Task

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, exit-code, post-build

I have a Visual Studio 2019 project with a Post-Build-Event, that is calling an EXE file I have written in C#.

Post-Build event:
`MyTool.exe "$(TargetPath)"`

This EXE file is doing some stuff and then calling another EXE file.
`AnotherTool.exe SomeArguments`

Problem is, if that second EXE file (AnotherTool.exe) gives an error (on StandardError output) or an exit code != 0, Visual Studio is "seeing" that codes, although the AnotherTool.exe is **not** called directly from the Post-Build event. The Post-Build just called the MyTool.exe.

I want MyTool.exe to handle that exit codes, so Visual Studio should ignore them. But the build fails, when AnotherTool.exe exits with an error.

Any ideas?

Edit: The "MyTool.exe" is calling the "AnotherTool.exe" using System.Diagnostics.Process. I set RedirectStandardOutput = true and RedirectStandardError = true, and then call the Process with Start() and WaitForExit().

But no matter what that process result is, MyTool.exe is always exiting with Environment.Exit(0) to give a clean exit.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but a Workaround that is working:

I created a batch file, that is calling:

`start MyTool.exe %1`

With this workaround, the build succeeds without error, and the tool chain is started correctly. I get no more error messages displayed in Visual Studio.

Trade off 1: The "MyTool.exe" is now displayed in a command window while running.

Trade off 2: If "MyTool.exe" fails with exit code != 0, Visual Studio won't notice.

If I remove the "start" from the batch, behaviour is like a direct call of MyTool.exe.